# Restarting Python Script after losing network Connection

Tags: python, networking, raspberry-pi, restart

I am wanting to send data from my Rasp Pi to another computer on a local network every X minutes. I have the python script to auto start at boot with a 3 min sleep timer so I am sure to establish a network connection. However, my internet connection will go in/out and my scripts' stop sending data. Is there a way to write a function that..

If network is down to restart the scripts?
Or in network is present do nothing?

Comment: What code are you using to initiate the connection? Can you simply reinitiate the connection every 3 minutes?

Comment: I am running a cron code at boot that says run sendInfo.py, which establishes the SFTP connection to the router and server. I have no problems at start up, but it is not until later that I loose connection and my scripts stop sending.

Comment: You should consider udp. It avoids the messy issues associated with timeouts and errors (if the network is unavailable).

Comment: I am unfamiliar with UDP and without changing my work too much, would it not be possible to just write another script that would check the two scripts i have at start up. If they have been killed or have errors to just restart?

Comment: Forget about UDP, that wasn't a useful note for your case. But shouldn't you be running the code in a loop and let the script restart the SFTP stuff whenever it times out?

Comment: I have the code that says:                                  Function to transmit data every x amount of time
Def transmitAndRemove
 Global nextTime
 nextTime = nextTime + interval
 sendAll()
 removeAll()

nextTIme = 60seconds

Comment: You could write another script to check for Internet connectivity (e.g. ping www.google.com) and if there is something wrong with the connectivity, restart your Python script. But as mentioned above, I can't see why all this can't be done inside a single Python script. In fact, I don't think you even need cron.

Comment: So after looking at the problem further I am still able to ping the pi from another computer even after it stops sending files. So is this a drop in the SSH connection by chance and not the network itself?